# How to conver URL to HREF for SVG Image

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, url, svg, href

How can I convert an `amazon presigned url` to a correct `href` attribute value for the svg image?

For example, here I have a url:

```
https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/zed-content/Dialogue%20Items/a0A1r00002sLxg9EACLeft/testImg.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJ7V4MJWO3GNAM6WA%2F20180710%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180710T133927Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-Signature=1044208e8a3fc4167fcd738637316d31a6b9a843063ec5658f8e7720c8963fb0&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
```

It url displays an image, but I do not know how to put the image situated behind the url as an svg image.

I am storing image using the `.jpg` extension. Now I would like to get the `href` for that image so that to display it using the image svg element.

In other words I want to have something like

```
<svg>
  <image href="IDoNotKnowWhatToPutInHere.jpg"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: The image in the link is stored as jpg. To display an image as svg, you'd need to store it as in svg-format first.

Comment: @Dunedan, I edited the question to reflect what you are talking about. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried putting the entire presigned URL in the `href` field?

Comment: @MarkB As one Mark B to another i can confirm that it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. Change the width and height to your liking's.

```css
.svg-main,
.svg-image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="svg-main">
  <image class="svg-image" href="https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/zed-content/Dialogue%20Items/a0A1r00002sLxg9EACLeft/testImg.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJ7V4MJWO3GNAM6WA%2F20180710%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180710T133927Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-Signature=1044208e8a3fc4167fcd738637316d31a6b9a843063ec5658f8e7720c8963fb0&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: You should probably use `xlink:href` for backward compatibility with SVG1.1.

Comment: And more than `xlink:href`, you must set `width` and `height` attributes for SVG1.1 support (it was not settable through CSS)